# Tensorflow 2 different batch size when doing inference

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, batchsize

I have made a custom model in tensorflow 2, which uses eager execution.
The model is trained using the inherited `.fit()` function, about 600k training samples are used in a 10 epoch cycle with a batch size of 128 (up to 8k batch has been done). After training the model is saved as a `SavedModel` format. This is then used in C++ by using the [cppflow library](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow). However, this process requires the inference to use the same batch size as the training of the model, while only requiring to do inference on a single sample at a time. The application requires that things are fast and padding a feature vector array with 127 dummy vectors is slowing everyting down.

The batch size is also used in the NormalizeLayer at the end, which is using a hardcoded units value at the moment to initialize a matrix.

I have searched for a way to use variable batch sizes in Tensorflow 2 custom models, but the only thing that is remotely close are TF1 examples; which are so outdated they are unusable.

My model:

```py
class IndividualFeaturesLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(IndividualFeaturesLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(input_shape[-1] + input_shape[-1])
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal((input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(input_shape[-1]), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

  def call(self, input):
    returnVar = tf.math.add(tf.matmul(input, self.w), self.b)
    return returnVar

class FullFeatureLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(FullFeatureLayer, self).__init__()

    self.globalFeatures = IndividualFeaturesLayer()
    self.pieceFeatures = IndividualFeaturesLayer()
    self.squareFeatures = IndividualFeaturesLayer()

  def call(self, input):
    globalFeature = input[:, :17]
    pieceFeature =  input[:, 17:225]
    squareFeature = input[:, 225:353]
    x = self.globalFeatures(globalFeature)
    y = self.pieceFeatures(pieceFeature)
    z = self.squareFeatures(squareFeature)

    returnVar = tf.concat([x, y, z], 1)
    return tf.nn.relu(returnVar)

class FullFullyConnectedFeatureLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(FullFullyConnectedFeatureLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(input_shape[-1] + input_shape[-1])
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal((input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(input_shape[-1]), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.math.add(tf.matmul(input, self.w), self.b))

class FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer, self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    stddev = 2 / np.sqrt(input_shape[-1] + 1)
    self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal((input_shape[-1], 1), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(1), dtype='float64'), trainable=True)

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.w) + self.b

class NormalizeLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, units=128):
    super(NormalizeLayer, self).__init__()
    self.units = units

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.divideTensor = tf.fill((self.units, 1), tf.constant(1500, dtype='float64'))
    self.minTensor = tf.fill((self.units, 1), tf.constant(-1, dtype='float64'))
    self.maxTensor = tf.fill((self.units, 1), tf.constant(1, dtype='float64'))

  def call(self, input):
    dividedTensor = tf.divide(input, self.divideTensor)

    minimizedTensor = tf.math.minimum(dividedTensor, self.maxTensor)

    maximizedTensor = tf.math.maximum(minimizedTensor, self.minTensor)

    return maximizedTensor

class FullNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, batch_size):
    super(FullNetwork, self).__init__(name='')

    self.inputLayer = FullFeatureLayer()
    self.hiddenLayer1 = FullFeatureLayer()
    self.hiddenLayer2 = FullFullyConnectedFeatureLayer()
    self.outputLayer = FullFullyConnectedOutputLayer()
    self.normalizeLayer = NormalizeLayer()


  def call(self, input, batch_size):
    print(batch_size)
    x = self.inputLayer(input)
    x = self.hiddenLayer1(x)
    x = self.hiddenLayer2(x)
    x = self.outputLayer(x)
    x = self.normalizeLayer(x)
    return x

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')
fullNetwork = FullNetwork()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
fullNetwork.compile(optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=["MeanAbsoluteError"], run_eagerly=True)
fullNetwork.fit(training_feature_array, training_score_array, epochs=10, batch_size=128)
```